# How can I hide that a ViewController is being initialized from a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm working on an ios app with many areas developed by multiple people.  We want a simple, standard paradigm of instantiating view controllers (frequently from other areas of the app), such as:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

However, we want the ability for our ViewControllers to be defined in Storyboards, where each area may have one or more storyboard.  How can we have the code that init's the UIViewControllers not be required to know the specifics of the storyboards?

Will something like the following work? (within MyViewController.m)

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyViewControllerStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    return [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
}
```

Or will the above cause memory leaks and/or other nasty side-effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a category that will have factory method for each special case of your view controller?

**Example:**

You have `MyViewControlle.h` and `MyViewController.m` along with `MyViewControllerStoryboard.storyboard`. You can create `MyViewController+FactoryMethods.h` and `MyViewController+FactoryMethods.m` files with following content:

**MyViewController+FactoryMethods.h**

```
@interface MyViewController (FactoryMethods)

+ (instancetype)createDefaultViewController();

@end
```

**MyViewController+FactoryMethods.m**

```
#import "MyViewController+FactoryMethods.h"
@implementatiion MyViewController (FactoryMethods)

+ (instancetype)createDefaultViewController() {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyViewControllerStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    return [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
}

@end
```

**Usage:**

```
#import "MyViewController+FactoryMethods.h"

@implementation SomeClass

- (void)method {
    MyViewController *mvc = [MyViewController createDefaultViewController];
}

@end
```

With this approach you will keep MyViewController files clean from factory methods. And approach is quite flexible since anybody in the team can easily extend the categories with custom factory methods. In addition everybody should quickly get used to looking for factory methods for controllers instantiation.